# LiNQ has different results

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this class called `Variables` which has multiple members and one of it is called `Name` which is a string. Supposed I have a `List<Variables>`. This has `Names`of `X`, `Y`, `Y`, `Z`.

```
string variableName = 'Y';

int _totalCount = (from p in variableList
                    where p.Name == variableName
                    select p.Name).Count();

int _totalCount2 = variableList.Select(x => x.Name == variableName).Count();
```

Question: Why is `_totalCount` returns `2` (*which is what I want*) while `_totalCount2` returns `4`?

Comment: Try replacing `.Select` with `.Where`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Select` is not doing what you think it does: it's a *projection*, not a *filter*.
The expression `x => x.Name == variableName` is calculated for each item on your list. You'll get `{False, True, True, False}`. Then the `Count()` gets called on the result, returning `4`.

Filtering is done with the `Where` method that takes a predicate:

```
int _totalCount2 = variableList.Where(x => x.Name == variableName).Count();
```

Comment: oh my bad, so what will I do to make it return `2`?

Comment: Thanks! but now I have another problem problem. When I added `Distinct` on both linq `.Distinct().Count();`, it shows 1 for the first while 2 for the second. Why is it not working?

Comment: @DerekFloss That's because your first example does a projection in addition to filtering. Add `Select(x => x.Name)` before `Distinct` to remove duplicate names.